# Arguement of type {label: string, value:string} [] is not assignable to paramter of type []. Type of property length are incompatible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

> Im working on a typescript web app, where in i need to pass an array
> of objects to a function.

```
const options = [
 { value: 'apple', label: 'Apple' },
  { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange' }
]

const handleChange = handleRadioCheck(options);
```

> Im getting error at the above line as stated in title

Comment: can you paste the code for your `handleRadioCheck` method ?

Comment: I cant share the client code here, its just like this  const handleRadioCheck = (options : []) =>{

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur, so `handleRadioCheck` accepts parameter of type `[]`, this is a tuple type and it accepts only and only an empty array, and you are trying to pass an array of objects, that's what causes the error. If you want `handleRadioCheck` accept any array, then use `options: any[]`, if you want array of objects like in your code snippet, use `options: { value: string, label: string}[]`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a parameter of type `{ value: string, label: string}[]` to a method that only accept `[]` as type.

You should either change the `handleRadioCheck` parameter type to accept `{ value: string, label: string}[]` or change your options values to be just an array like [] and not a set of key values.

Answer (score 0):

please paste your handleRadioCheck function code. I believe you are passing the wrong parameter type to it. but for a quick fix. you can change the parameter type in you handleRadioCheck to 'any' it will fix it